# What is wrong with this reasoning regarding the triangle inequality??

Tags: inequality

$$ |a + b|  \leq |a| + |b| $$

$$ |a - b|  \leq |a| + |b| $$

$$ |a + b| - |a - b| \leq 0 $$

$$ |a + b|  \leq |a - b| $$

But this inequality is obviously not satisfied for $a=1 , b=2$. I guess the mistake is in the 3rd step but I cant convince myself why that is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with absolute values. From

$$ x < M $$ 
and
$$ y < M$$

it does not follow that

$$
x - y < M - M = 0 .
$$

Stated this way you should be able to see obvious counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

At least one wrong step is from line 2 to 3. If you could do that (subtracting lhs and rhs separately), then there is no reason you couldn't do it the other way around. I.e. $$|a-b| - |a+b| \leq 0$$ instead. But if both that line and the third line are true then it has to be equality which is a contradiction since obviously $|a+b| \neq |a-b|$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

The third inequality is not true in general. For $a$ and $b$ positive it is not true.

**Hint:** When adding (or substracting) inequalities you have to be careful with the direction of the inequalities.